# How to adjust figure settings in plotmatrix?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I adjust the point size, alpha, font, and axis ticks in a plotmatrix?

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
plotmatrix(iris)
```

[image]

How can I:

- make the points twice as big
- set alpha = 0.5
- have no more than 5 ticks on each axis
- set font to 1/2 size?

I have fiddled with the `mapping = aes()` argument to `plotmatrix` as well as `opts()` and adding layers such as `+ geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size = 14)`, but none of these seem to do anything. I have hacked a bit of a fix to the size by writing to a large pdf (`pdf(file = "foo.pdf", height = 10, width = 10)`), but this provides only a limited amount of control.

Comment: Most of those things worked for me by doing the obvious thing, but most people use `ggpairs` from **GGally** for this kind of thing, I think.

Comment: @joran that is a good hint, but `ggpairs(iris, alpha = 0.1, size = 0.1)` results in a small change to alpha and none to size.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much all of the **ggplot2** scatterplot matrix options are still fairly new and can be a bit experimental.

But the facilities in **GGally** *do* allows you to construct this kind of plot manually, though:

```
custom_iris <- ggpairs(iris,upper = "blank",lower = "blank",
                       title = "Custom Example")

p1 <- ggplot(iris,aes(x = Sepal.Length,y = Sepal.Width)) + 
          geom_point(size = 1,alpha = 0.3)
p2 <- ggplot(iris,aes(x = Sepal.Width,y = Sepal.Length)) + 
          geom_point()

custom_iris <- putPlot(custom_iris,p1,2,1)
custom_iris <- putPlot(custom_iris,p2,3,2)

custom_iris
```

[image]

I did that simply by directly following the last example in `?ggpairs`.

Comment: is it possible to set the size and alpha of all plots in the lower triangle without having to create each plot separately? I have a 12x12 matrix ... (by separately, I mean without a loop or vectorizing a custom function)

Comment: @Abe Hard to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: @Abe Using this method you'll have to create each plot separately anyway, so I don't see the point.

Comment: I don't quite understand. `ggpairs(iris)` produces plots all at once. Are you saying that the only to set the alpha value is to create each plot separately, or the only way to do this using the `putPlot` method is to create each plot separately?

Comment: @Abe As I noted in my answer, these plot matrix functions are still a bit rough around the edges. You noted that simply setting alpha didn't work. I suggested a work around involving constructing each plot separately, which as I demonstrated allows you to control the aesthetic in each plot the way you'd expect.